# Where is the MVC 3 razor templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, t4

I want to see the content of the T4 templates that are used by visual studio to generate MVC 3 razor views (create, list, etc). Where can I find those templates and what are the names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of express edition it is located in this folder of visual studio installation.

> Common7\IDE\VWDExpress\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\

and for visual studio

> Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates

EDIT: Replace CSharp with VisualBasic for that version